# Fading out a div and refreshing the page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given that I have a button within a div:

```
<div id="result">
        <a href='#task5'>
        <img src='resources/book.png' style='padding-top: 10px;'
        class='button3'>
        </a>
</div>
```

How would I use jquery or javascript to:

1) Fade out the div

2) Refresh the page

3) Automatically jump to an anchor called #t5 on the page

This is what I have so far but I'm having difficulty jumping to an anchor called t5:

```
$(".button4").click(function (){
    $("#result").fadeOut(function(){
        location.reload();
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems simple, but I'm actually not sure of a simple way to refresh the page and THEN set a hash.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I've done so far. Sorry @GrailsGuy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can give you a hint how to implement it

```
    $("#result").fadeOut(function(){
    // Heres the callback when the animation is complete
        window.location = window.location + "#t5";
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NxKFp/1/

You don't provide exactly what you want to do. So I think it will exist more easy way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This would jump to `#task5` and not `#t5`.

Comment: Thats a very good point and my misstake ;-) I will update the example

Comment: Please check my updated question for further details.

Comment: It doesn't refresh the page. It just adds #t5 to the address - the result is so the result is: `page.php#t5#t5`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get it why would you fade out that div but here's how to do it

```
$('#result').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    var url = window.location;
    window.location = url + "#t5";
});
```

Comment: It doesn't refresh the page. It just adds #t5 to the address - the result is so the result is: `page.php#t5#t5`.